# User not being authenticated, when trying to send a post request using react JS

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, reactjs, passport.js

I am following a video tutorial which shows how to authenticate a user using node and passport JS. This tutorial uses Hogan JS for as its view engine, however I want to follow the tutorial using React as my front end,
everything works fine on the server side, if I test it with postman, i.e, the user is authenticated, serialized, deserialized and the session gets stored, but as soon as I try it while accessing it from my react, The user does not get authenticated even though I am getting a correct user at the serialize function.

Here is my server file:

```
const express = require('express');
const session = require('express-session');
const passport = require('passport');
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');
require('./passport');

express()
  .use(bodyParser.json())
  .use(bodyParser.urlencoded({extended: false}))
  .use(session({ secret: 'i love dogs', resave: false, saveUninitialized: false }))
  .use(passport.initialize())
  .use(passport.session())
  .get('/', (req, res, next) => {
    res.json({
      session: req.session,
      user: req.user,
      authenticated: req.isAuthenticated()
    });
  })
  .get('/login', (req, res, next) => {
    res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*');
    res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Headers', 'Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept');
    res.json({name: 'login again'});
  })
  .post('/login', (req, res, next) => {
    res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*');
    res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Headers', 'Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept');
    next();
  }, passport.authenticate('local', {
    successRedirect: '/',
    failureRedirect: '/login'
  }))
  .listen(3001)
;
```

Here is my Passport file:

```
const passport = require('passport');
const LocalStrategy = require('passport-local').Strategy;
const mongo = require('./db');
const ObjectId = require('mongodb').ObjectId;

passport.use(new LocalStrategy(authenticate));

function authenticate (email, password, done) {
  mongo.db.collection('users').find({email}).toArray((err, user) => {
    if (err) return done(null, false, {message: err});
    if (user.length === 0 || user[0].password !== password) {
      return done(null, false, {message: 'Invalid user and password combination'});
    }
    done(null, user);
  });
}

passport.serializeUser((user, done) => {
  done(null, user[0]._id);
  console.log(user);
});

passport.deserializeUser((id, done) => {
  console.log(id);
  mongo.db.collection('users').find({_id: ObjectId(id)}).toArray((err, user) => {
    if (err) return done(null, false, {message: err});
    done(null, user);
  });
});
```

and here is the react login component:

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';

export default class Login extends Component {
  constructor (props) {
    super(props);

    this.onFormSubmit = this.onFormSubmit.bind(this);
  }

  onFormSubmit (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    const { username, password } = this.refs;
    fetch(`http://localhost:3001/login?username=${username.value}&password=${password.value}`, {
      method: 'post'
    })
      .then(blob => blob.json())
      .then(res => {
        console.log(res);
      });
  }

  render () {
    return (
      <form onSubmit={this.onFormSubmit}>
        <div>
          <label>Email:</label>
          <input type='text' ref='username' />
        </div>
        <div>
          <label>Password:</label>
          <input type='password' ref='password' />
        </div>
        <div>
          <input type='submit' value='Log In' />
        </div>
      </form>
    );
  }
}
```

For the complete link of my project, here's the 
[Github Link](https://github.com/aditya2337/nodePlusReact/tree/master/loginSessions)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Wow, I just figured out the answer,I just had to include:

```
credentials: 'include',
```

in the fetch method, and the set the headers to allow my server origin and set the allow credential headers to be true, here's how I did it:

```
res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', 'http://localhost:3000');
res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Credentials', true);
```

This took me a whole day to get to this solution.